# differentiating a differentiable form. I know this has been asked but I don't get it so I'm going to ask through the easiest example.

Tags: calculus, manifolds

if $a =  ydx + xdy$. I know this is a 1 form on let's say $R^{2}$.

To evaluate $da$, we write it as $d(ydx+xdy)$ and then distribute it as
$d(ydx) + d(xdy)$. Now do I apply the chain rule to get this:
$dydx + ydxdx(=0) + dxdy + xdydy(=0)$

$= dydx + dxdy = 0$

or

this: $dydx + yd^{2}x + dxdy + x^{2}dy $

which one is correct?

Comment: if the former last step is correct, then why is $d(dx) = dxdx$ and not $d(dx)=d^{2}x$

Comment: Your product rule, has it already been proven for e.g. the product of $n$-form against $m$-form?

Comment: I'm not even sure about the product rule. that's why I'm asking.

Comment: $d(dx) = 0$ (as a 2-form) since $dx$ is exact, which therefore agrees with  $dx \wedge dx =0$ because $\wedge$ is anti-commutative, but the reasoning is a little indirect. Can you state any product rule you are sure about? Besides just $d$ of functions

Comment: how about this. can i do this. $d(xdx)$. Let $z=dx \implies d(xz) = d(x).z + x.d(z) \implies dx.dx + xd^{2}x = xd^{2}x  $

Comment: the result is correct because you end up with $= 0$ since $d^2  = 0$. Alternatively use that $xdx = d(x^2/2)$, then $d^2=0$ gives the result without using product rule. It looks like a correct application of product rule, but you haven't stated your product rule (also, do you not use $\wedge$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product rule for the wedge product (which is what you have) of a $p$-form $\alpha$ and a $q$-form $\beta$ is
\begin{equation}
d(\alpha\wedge\beta) =d \alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^p\alpha\wedge d\beta.
\end{equation}
Note that the degree of $\beta$ actually plays no role.

The chain rule does not play a role in the case you are considering ($y$ is not a function of $x$), instead you apply the product rule, like you did in your second attempt, *and* the fact that $d^2=0$, so $d^2x=d^2y=0$.

So $da=0$. In fact, more holds: there is a 0-form, that is a function, $f$ such that $a = df$. Can you find $f$?

By $d^2=0$, exact forms (exterior derivative of another form) like then one you have are always closed (that is their exterior derivative vanishes). However, there are closed forms which are not exact. The prototypical example is the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{x dy- y dx}{x^2 +y^2}
\end{equation}
defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$.